# Linking JS to Google app script to run functions based on checkbox on web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create an IF statement in JS that triggers two different functions in google script based on the whether the checkbox is checked or not, the GS functions are working fine, they are supposed to set the value of a certain cell to TRUE or FALSE, however I cannot tie them to the checkbox in the web app.

The Google script:

```
function doGet(){

 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page');
}

function check1(x){
 SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Aj3O9sidPncQ4tbiXOP8x27dWp9V8I-XQ6v184iZnT4").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A2").setValue("TRUE");
}

function check2(x){
 SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Aj3O9sidPncQ4tbiXOP8x27dWp9V8I-XQ6v184iZnT4").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A2").setValue("FALSE");
  
  
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
  }
```

The Javascript:

```
<script>
  
function doStuff() {
  //Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  
 if (checkBox.checked == true){  
 google.script.run.check1();
} else {

google.script.run.check2();}
 
  };
   
  </script>
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="doStuff()">


</html>
```

Thanks in advance,,,

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, you haven't shown how you've linked `doStuff` to the HTML checkbox.  I would expect the `<script> ` to register an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) that will run `doStuff` on some event.  Which event?  Do you want the checkbox change event?  If you're trying to use a form submit event, [review the guide carefully](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms).  If you update your question to include all the HTML, it may help.

Comment: HTML added. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... nothing obviously wrong to me.  I'm assuming the `<html>` and `<script>` snippets shown end up in the same HTML document, but can you confirm that?  Have you verified `doStuff` runs?  You could verify with a `console.log` inside `doStuff`.  If `doStuff` seems to run, you can add a `console.log` on the server.  You can also use `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(console.error).check1()` to display server-side errors client-side in case you are somehow missing an error message.

Comment: no logs seem to appear

Comment: The only remaining clue is that you are using [`include`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript) incorrectly.  If you are using `include` inside `Page.html`, then you need to use `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate()`.  Otherwise the `<script>` will never be included.  Can you confirm or explain whether include is used in `Page.html`?

Comment: I do not have include in my Page.html, how do you suggest I add it?

Comment: Update your question to show us what `Page.html` looks like.  You do not _need_ the `include` function, but you did post it in your question, so I assumed you either used it or meant to use it.